# What kind of validations to do with FluentValidations?

Tags: c#, .net, validation, fluentvalidation

In the context of a data-oriented application, that uses a database:

I was using `FluentValidations` only to validate things like that an Id was a positive number, or that an argument isn't `null`: **Things that didn't hit the database**.

But after some time, I wondered why wouldn't I validate things that **actually query the database**. So I decided to validate further and now, my `Validator` not only validates that the specified Id is a positive number, but **also that the entity exists**.

Is this the goal of a Validator. Am I misusing it? Should a Validator check also complex business rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, it's totally fine to use `FluentValidator` for checking business rules. But it's better to separate business rules from simple validation. For example if it's ASP.NET application general validation should be performed in the Presentation layer(like using `ModelState`) but business rules should come into play in the Domain layer(e.g. in some service or [decorator](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aop.html#decoration)).

You can find these links useful:

1. [ValidateModelAttribute](http://blog.karbyn.com/articles/fluent-validation-in-web-api/)
2. [Validate command using Decorator pattern](https://codeopinion.com/validating-commands/)
3. [Simple Injector(fast DI container, great for decorators)](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Thanks! What's the general rule of thumb? I'm doing a Web API and the Validators act against each of the requests. Maybe, a Validator in this aspect can intercept common things like a GetById where the Id is not found. But, does it make sense to validate a complex condition that the request should meet according to the business rules? Or should I perform the validation in a lower layer and just throw an appropriate exception when the condition isn't met?

Comment: It depends on your requirements. I guess it makes sense to perform basic validation in your controllers(you can try to integrate FluentValidation to built-in pipeline and just use ModelState or fetch validator by itself and call Validate manually) and just return 400 in case of failure. But for more complex, domain and DB related validations you'd better validate your entity in some lower layer(I hope you have some service, repository or command handler). It also can be done manually or using decorator/interceptor. To indicate a failure you can throw an exception or return a validation result

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do this kind of validations:
1.Create a class and inherit from ProperyValidator and use it to the entity validations class.

```
public class UniqueValidator<T> : PropertyValidator where T:class
{
 //inject the repository
 protected override bool isValid(PropertyValidatorContext context){
  //check the validity
 }
}
```

2.Create method directy to the EntityValidation class

```
public class EntityValidation : AbstractValdiation<Entity>{
 //inject the repository


 //your current validations

 public bool UniqueValue(Entity instance){
   //query to validate
 }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm asking whether it's a bad idea to check complex business logic inside a validator or not.